# How to ensure that files uploaded by users do not contain any Javascript

Tags: javascript, attack-prevention, file-upload

I'm trying to make a file uploader using [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/), but it is vulnerable to scripts: If someone tries to upload a file (e.g. a résumé) that includes JavaScript, this could get executed once the file upload is completed.

Are there efficient ways to detect JavaScript code? I know parsing the file can detect the code, but I consider parsing every file that's uploaded a bad idea because it consumes processing power.

Comment: There are a range of solutions, but I wanted to ask - why is parsing these files not a good idea?

Comment: Rather then checking the uploaded file for executable content, you should prevent the file from being executed as javascript.

Comment: Why the `java` tag? Java is not Javascript. Is your only concern HTML files with Javascript embedded? What about malicious PDFs, executables or other formats which may have buggy clients?

Comment: @user19426 Thanks a lot showing interest. In addition to what you said, in fact i was also wondering how google docs is preventing such attacks. Your solution seems quite promising & i appreciate it. I'll really be grateful to you could tell me how could i prevent this kind of javascript getting executed on server.

Comment: @Lekensteyn PrimeFaces appears to be written in Java, so the java tag is appropriate.

Comment: You could send the uploaded files as *application/octet-stream*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be attempting to do this as there is no way you will detect all malicious script. There are various ways of hiding it as it isn't all nicely presented within `<script>` tags. Take this one for example:

```
<BODY onload!#$%&()*~+-_.,:;?@[/|\]^`=alert("XSS")>
```

Check out the [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) for some other examples.

If you are displaying the uploaded files in HTML, then you should set a [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) to prevent inline JavaScript and CSS from running. (Using CSS it is possible to embed JavaScript. Some versions of Internet Explorer support this)

The CSP can prevent inline script, but allow script to run in external `js` files from your server or from trusted sources (such as Google CDN).

You would need to make sure that you validate that the browser supports CSP first (you could implement a test for this in a page before displaying the content), and you could do this in combination with a HTML sanitizer that processes the page content only on *output* to the browser. This will be a belt and braces approach. You should use a well tested solution for the sanitization, such as [OWASP AntiSamy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project). Vulnerabilities have been found in older versions of most sanitizers (even this one), but using it in combination with a CSP would prevent most attacks as this would give you the window of time to patch to the latest version.

The other option would be to add the [Content Disposition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1012437/413180) header to any served content, so that it would be downloaded to the user's machine rather than displaying in a browser in the context of your domain. Any code running in the context of your domain can take advantage of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) to attack users viewing the content. This would not be possible offline (Internet Explorer gives a warning message with confirmation prompt, and browsers such as Chrome and Firefox treat the file system as the `null` origin to stop the script accessing online content).

Answer (score 0):

The file needs to be inspected before storing it. To detect embedded JavaScript code, you'll have no other option than parsing the entire contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just have a simple query. Google docs is also similar kinda product. So do they also follow the same fashion i.e. parsing every file getting uploaded. I doubt. Please help me understanding this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to look into that file to ensure that there's no JavaScript in there. But that could be as simple as searching for tokens like '(', ')' and ';' (f.e., not sure whether this is sufficient...). Of course when doing this, these letters can't occur any more in regular content. So if your 'personal' definition of parsing is 'doing complex operations on the file like f.e. building a parse tree of it', then this is a solution without parsing.

However, the preferrable solution to your problem would be to make sure no JavaScript can be executed, no matter whether it's in the file or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot showing interest. In addition to what you said, in fact i was also wondering how google docs is preventing such attacks. Your solution seems quite promising & i appreciate it. I'll really be grateful to you could tell me how could i prevent this kind of javascript getting executed on server

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to prevent a cross-site scripting ("XSS") attack. You could attempt to run some string replacements to replace certain characters with their HTML entities (like `<script>` with `&lt;script&gt;`) to prevent a web browser from recognizing them as code to execute while still displaying them the way the user entered them, but when it comes to security it is always better to trust a proven solution than to roll your own.

There are a lot of edge-cases which allow to embed javascript in HTML you might forget about. But when you use a well-known library designed by web security specialists and recommended by other equally capable specialists, you can assume that they have these eventualities covered.

There are many libraries available especially for this purpose. You tagged this question as Java, so I assume that you are using Java (JSP?) for your server-sided programming. The question "[XSS prevention in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java)" on Stackoverflow lists some libraries you can use.

Try to sanitize user inputs as soon as the server receives it. The longer you keep the unsanitized strings around, the higher the risk that they leak somewhere, like into an error message in a log which someone then views with a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options here:

1. Parse the files and make sure you get it right.  You can't just remove script tags, you also need to remove attributes that enable scripting, make sure links don't have javascript: scheme URIs, etc.  If you choose this route, I suggest using something like [OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project), rather than trying to implement it yourself, as it's non-trivial.
2. Stop caring about it.  Put the files where they can't do any harm.  This is an approach taken by many sites that serve up user-generated content.  If the pages are served from an origin that doesn't contain sensitive content & doesn't have sensitive cookies, then an XSS is not able to compromise anything.  If you serve the files from "useruploadedcontent.com", then due to [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) the scripts are only able to interact with "useruploadedcontent.com" and not "domainwithsensitivecookies.com".